# xclip from non-bash shell not enduring

Tags: bash, shell, tcl, tk-toolkit, xclip

In bash, `echo toast | xclip -sel c` saves the toast inside the clipboard, even when I close the terminal. Why does this seem to be non-persistent from other shells?

python3.5:

```
import os
os.system("echo toast | xclip -sel c")
```

Does the job, but when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>, the clipboard is empty. A simple <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> does *not* clear the clipboard / works fine.

tclsh:

```
exec /bin/echo toast | xclip -sel c
```

Even keeps the process open, so I have to terminate it.

Is this a bug? How is this even possible? Or what am I misunderstanding?

Edit. cannot find a solution for this. I made a `wish` (Tcl/Tk)-script, included a `exec /bin/echo toast | xclip -sel c` line and closed the window. The clipboard is now *empty*. I tried -display, but both display and xauthority are set properly. The same problems were occuring with pythons pyperclip and xerox.

Edit2. the issue can be reduced to this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/316715/xclip-works-differently-in-interactive-and-non-interactive-shells and there does not seem to be a good alternative other than using `xsel -ib` for storing clipboards.

Comment: you may know this, but `exec` (at least in `(ba|k|c)*sh` creates a new process and overlays it on the existing. Maybe `tclsh` is different, but I would expect to lose access to ex-parent data in that case too. I don't know about `python`, but seems like the evidence supports the same intrepretation/idea/concept. Sorry I can't provide direct documentation about how `exec` works in shells, but if  you search around a little bit you may find it. BUT happy to be corrected/enlightend by the +50K shell crowd. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to continue pipeline or redirect output. For me its work in tcl:

```
exec printf "%s" $var | xclip -selection c | echo
```

or:

```
exec printf "%s" $var | xclip -selection c > /dev/null
```

Comment: Thanks, but for me this doesn't seem to do anything. https://i.imgur.com/Jz8mpA3.png

Comment: In tclsh and scripts use `exit` command instead of Ctrl+C. https://i.imgur.com/YRtljGu.png

Comment: using exit is actually the key to this. note that instead of `| echo` or `> /dev/null`, job control with  `&` will also do. thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, but `&` dont wait for process end. https://i.imgur.com/81wOuDM.png